# I am not able to open the IIS express application

Tags: iis, iis-express

I am not able to open the IIS express application. Whenever I run it, it shows the application is running. I can see the application running in the taskbar but when I click it to see the application, the application is not loading up.
I have tried to run the application as the administrator and tried to repair it but still the application is still not opening.

I can't get the IIS Express application to open. It appears the application is running each time I run it. Although I can see the application running in the taskbar, it does not load when I click on it to do so. Even after running the application as the administrator and trying to repair it, it still won't launch.

Comment: You should learn how to launch IIS Express from command line https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/using-iis-express/running-iis-express-from-the-command-line or use a tool like Jexus Manager https://docs.jexusmanager.com/getting-started/features.html

Comment: Do you get any error messages when you try to start IIS Express from Visual Studio? Have you tried restarting the machine?

Comment: @YurongDai I am not getting any errors  as the application is running in background. i have restarted the system as well multiple times.

Comment: This is a guess, the port is being used by another process, causing the application to fail to start. You can check if the port is used by another application by running the netstat command.

Comment: I have checked it, port is not being used by any other process

Comment: Have you tried running IIS from the command line?

Comment: Yes I have tried running through the commandline, My commands are executing without any error. 
But still not able to open the application.

Comment: Please check to see if any firewall or antivirus software is blocking the application from running. Try disabling them temporarily and see if that fixes the problem.

Comment: Thank you YurongDai for help. I went through your solution. thanks it helped me.

Comment: Glad you got it working! I have turned the comments into an answer. If this helps you, you could click '✔' to mark it as an answer. It will also help others with similar problems. See also https://stackoverflow.com/help/why-vote

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you encounter a situation where you cannot open an IIS Express application, the following are some steps you can take to fix the problem.

1. Check that you have sufficient privileges to run the application. Please make sure you are running the application as administrator.
2. Check if there are any port conflicts. If the port used by the application is already in use by another application, it can prevent the application from loading up. You can check if the port is used by other applications by running the netstat command. If so, try changing the port and see if that fixes the problem.
3. Check if there are any firewall or antivirus software blocking the application from running. Please try disabling them temporarily and see if it resolves the issue.